# how to pass tuple as function arguments

Tags: julia

Got a function that takes three arguments.

```
f(a, b, c) = # do stuff
```

And another function that returns a tuple.

```
g() = (1, 2, 3)
```

How do I pass the tuple as function arguments?

```
f(g()) # ERROR
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Using Nanashi's example, the clue is the error when you call `f(g())`

```
julia> g() = (1, 2, 3)
g (generic function with 1 method)

julia> f(a, b, c) = +(a, b, c)
f (generic function with 1 method)

julia> g()
(1,2,3)

julia> f(g())
ERROR: no method f((Int64,Int64,Int64))
```

This indicates that this gives the tuple `(1, 2, 3)` as the input to `f` without unpacking it.  To unpack it use an ellipsis.

```
julia> f(g()...)
6
```

The relevant section in the Julia manual is here: http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/manual/functions/#varargs-functions

Comment: I prefer `f(g()...)` over `apply`, and I think the first is more idiomatic in Julia.

Comment: @AJcodez: Is it possible to remove my answer as the accepted one and mark this one as the answer instead? I believe this is better anyway.

Comment: The docs seemed to have moved. Today's link is https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/functions/#Varargs-Functions-1

Answer (score 6):

**Answer outdated as of Julia version 0.4, released in 2015:**

In modern versions of Julia, use the `...` operator `f(g()...)`.

---

Use **[`apply`](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/stdlib/base/#Base.apply)**.

```
julia> g() = (1,2,3)
g (generic function with 1 method)

julia> f(a,b,c) = +(a,b,c)
f (generic function with 1 method)

julia> apply(f,g())
6
```

Let us know if this helps.