# Julia: Unpack Arguments from Dictionary or Array for Functions with Multiple Dispatch

Tags: julia, multiple-dispatch

My question originated where I had a dictionary of DataFrame values (with compatible columns), and I want to `vcat` them all together.

Consider how the `string` function can take any number of string arguments:
`string("Fish ", "and ", "chips ") == "Fish and chips "` (is `true`). I have a dictionary
`myLunch = Dict(:a => "Fish ", :b => "and ", :c => "chips ")`
and I want to unpack the dictionary and pass its values to `string` as though they were arguments.

`string( unpack(myLunch)) == "Fish and chips "`

Analogously, my data might be stored in an array, `lunch = ["Fish ", "and ", "chips "]`, and I want to pass the array's contents as arguments:

`string( unpack(lunch) )`

How can you do this?

[Here is a related post on StackOverflow for tuples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22873478/how-to-pass-tuple-as-function-arguments)

Comment: It depends on whether you care about order -- dictionaries are unordered, so you might get any permutation using `keys`.

Answer (score 4):

First a little renaming for clarity:

```
luncharray = ["Fish ", "and ", "chips "]
lunchdict = Dict(:a => "Fish ", :b => "and ", :c => "chips ")
```

For an array, you just splat it into several arguments, just like you could for a tuple:

```
string(luncharray...)
```

Dictionaries are key-value pairs, and you can iterate over its values. You can splat any iterable into several arguments:

```
# don't care about order
       # only need values of Dict
string(values(lunchdict)...)
```

The problem with the dictionary is that it doesn't preserve an order like arrays do; you can't even count on insertion order. It's possible to get something like `and Chips Fish` . Therefore, we have to sort it ourselves. Coincidentally, `["Fish", "and", "Chips"]` is already in order, but we usually don't want to sort by words. Your keys are `:a, :b, :c` to indicate order, so lets sort by that.

```
# care about order
        # value from key   # sort an array of keys in the Dict
string((lunchdict[key] for key in sort(collect(keys(lunchdict))))...)
```

Comment: +1. @Owen depending what you are actually doing you might have a peek at DataStructures.jl and SortedDict

Comment: This works for dictionaries of strings, with the string function, but would it also work for dictionaries of DataFrames with another function? ie. could I `vcat( (dataFrameDictionary[key] for key in [:a,:b,:c])... )` ?

Comment: The unpacked DataFrames will act properly as separate arguments for `vcat`, if that's what you're asking. It could fail for a different reason; `vcat`'s keyword argument `cols` has the value `:setequal` by default, which requires all input DataFrames to have the same column names. Read `vcat`'s documentation for the full details.